# alternatives for 'finding your feet'

Tags: idioms, colloquialisms, idiom-requests

I need alternatives for the expression

> *finding your feet*
>    or
>   *getting used to something / doing something*

Can anyone help?

Comment: More context might help narrow it. The phrase roughly means *becoming adept in*.

Comment: How about "getting the hang of it"?

Answer (score 1):

Being or feeling "in the zone", I believe was originally a sport metaphor.

"Mastering" your subject maybe boastful.

"Getting there"

Finally "climbing/ascending off that plateau".

The "steep learning curve" is finally "leveling out".

Less and less is going "over your head".

Getting your "game face on straight"

I'm sure that there are many more, but I haven't gotten "in(+to) the right head-space" at the moment to think of them. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an alternative idiom, I can't think of one right now.

However you could consider saying "get accustomed" or "adapt to". Though the use of each may differ on the basis of context.